# React / React-native - Get children of custom component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im trying to write a module that can loop through a component's children and find an element of a certain type.

I have been unsuccessful in finding a way to destructure a custom component's building blocks and seeing what elements are being used to build up that custom component.

```
function recursiveMap(children, fn) {
  return React.Children.map(children, (child, i) => {
    if (!React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return child
    }
    if (child.props.children) {
      child = React.cloneElement(child, {
        children: recursiveMap(child.props.children, fn)
      })
    }
    return fn(child, i)
  })
}
```

With this code I am able to loop through a component's children tree, but I want to be able to see each custom component's building blocks, whichever they are other custom components or basic html elements.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use child.type.displayName to get the name of children tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the component's name in the property displayName. If you're using ES6 classes, you can set a static property called displayName into component's class. Then, you'll be able to get the child name with child.type.displayName.

```
const FirstChild = ({ name }) => <li>{name}</li>;
FirstChild.displayName = 'FirstChild';

const SecondChild = ({ name }) => <li>{name}</li>;
SecondChild.displayName = 'SecondChild';

class ThirdChild extends React.Component {
  static displayName = 'ThirdChild';

  render() {
    return (
      <li>{this.props.name}</li>
    );
  }

}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, child => {
      console.log('name =', child.type.displayName);
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>{this.props.children}</ul>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Parent>
        <FirstChild name='1st child value' />
        <SecondChild name='2nd child value' />
        <ThirdChild name='3rd child value' />
      </Parent>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Or

To get the tags you can loop through the children and get the type from it

```
children.map(e => {
console.log(e.type) // This will get you call the tags
})
```